# Fetching a long text column

Tags: python, mysql

I've got a problem with fetching a result from a MySql database with Python3.6.
The long text is a numpy array transformed into a string.

When I check the database and look into the column `img_array` everything is just fine. All the data is written.

Next I try to retrieve the text column like this:

```
con = .. # SQL connection which is successful and working fine
cur = con.cursor() # Getting the cursor
cur.execute('SELECT img_array FROM table WHERE id = 1')
result = cur.fetchone()[0] # Result is a tuple with the array at 0
print(result)
[136 90 87 ... 66 96 125]
```

The problem here is that the `...` is like a string. I'm missing all the values.

When I try the following it works just fine:

```
cur.execute('SELECT img_array FROM table LIMIT 1')
result = cur.fetchone()[0] # this gives me the entire string in the DB
print(result)
# The entire array will be printed here without missing values
```

I really don't know how to fetch a column with the where clause via python.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Ok, the last edit was wrong... I've checked it again and the buffered cursor doesn't change it. I'm confused because it seemed to work.

Comment: I don't know what _exactly_ is best practice, but I wouldn't personally be storing arrays like this. Maybe as HDF5 files and then store the file name in the DB. You're going to have a hard time getting it from the DB back into a usable array.

Comment: It's actually not that hard. I simply use the numpy fromstring/tostring method which converts everything just fine.
The probelm is that i cannot get the entire entry for the column when i use there 'where' clause.

Comment: Which is precisely my point. Saying something isn't hard, when the alternative doesn't work, doesn't really make sense.

Comment: nothing wrong with using the buffered flag but you should read why that is here —> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffered.html

Comment: @roganjosh Well i agree with you but I have to save the array in that format.
And wouldn't the problem also exist if it was a very long string?